# SQL query to insert/update the qty depending on the condition(unable to insert)

Tags: sql, database, sql-insert

I have a table like Item

```
ItemID ItemName 
1        a          
2        b
```

Component table

```
cid  name   rate
12    ff      2
13    tt      4
14    ff      4
15    ff      2
```

compenent_item

```
pk_id    cid    itemid    qty
1         12     1          3
2         13     1         4
3         14     1         4
4         15     1         4
5         12     2          3
6         13     2         4
7         14     2         4
8         15     2         4
```

I have to insert in my component_item table depending on the case if itemid and cid doesnt exist in my component table.

I am unable to make correct query

Comment: Also, tag the DBMS you are using.

Comment: Your language is a bit ambiguous.  If component_item had no rows in it, does that mean you'd want to insert the cross-product of "Item" and "Component" into it? (8 rows in your example)? This would likely make future updates very costly as component and item grew.

Comment: Look for a MERGE command.

Answer (score 0):

except I don't know what value you want for qty...

```
Insert compenent_item(cid, itemId, qty)
Select i.ItemId, c.cid, ??
from Item I 
   full join component c
where not exists(Select * from compenent_item
                 where cid = c.cid
                    and itemId = i.ItemID)
```